# How To Merge Database Tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

Please, i have an issue requiring help. I have gone through similar questions asked by other users, but none seems to solve mine.

I have 3 tables (exam, test, classworks), with similar colums that store scores for different subjects i.e english, maths, rhyme. it identifies students using their assigned ID. i want to be able to add the score of each subject to get a value so i can compare with other students using loop. i.e in Maths, A student scored in exam 45, in test 20, in classwork 20. Total will be 85.. How do i merge this table in a similar query like the one below for easy manipulation:

```
require_once("con.php");

$class="Preschool1";

$id="12345";

$project = mysqli_query(
             $mysqli,
             "SELECT * FROM `exam` WHERE `class`='".$class."' && `ID`='".$id."'  ")
           or die("Database not found");
if(mysqli_num_rows($project)==true)
{
    $parray=mysqli_fetch_array($project);
}

else
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: could you not join by student id?

Comment: have tried it out but can't wrap my head around it, seems not to work. thats y i need someone to assist with the query rightly..

Comment: It might help you wrap your head around it better if you create another table called `students`. Then try adding the 3 joins one at a time on `students.id` and echo the result to see what you're getting. Also it is bad practice to put variables directly into a query. Instead use bound parameters.

Comment: Can you please write the query the way it ought to be, join the tables on id, so i can get the values of each subject and add them up. I can take it up from there.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Was also able to get records of a particular individual from all table, and manipulate as i please.. thank you

```
<?php
include 'con.php';
$name="Stanley Macron";
$sql = '
SELECT 
project_nursery.fname as fname,
project_nursery.sn as sn,
project_nursery.Literacy as literacy,
project_nursery.Numeracy as numeracy,
nursery_result_exam.sn as sn2,
nursery_result_exam.fname as fname2,
nursery_result_exam.Literacy as literacy2,
        nursery_result_exam.Numeracy as numeracy2
    FROM Project_nursery
    LEFT JOIN nursery_result_exam ON (project_nursery.fname = nursery_result_exam.fname)';

if($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
                     $fname=$row['fname'];


        if($name==$fname)
        {

        echo "  <table class=\"table table-bordered\">";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>sn</th>";
        echo "<th>Name</th>";
        echo "<th>P Literacy</th>";
        echo "<th>E Literact</th>";
        echo "<th>sn</th>";
        echo "<th>P Numeracy</th>";
        echo "<th>E Numeracy</th>";

        echo "</tr>";

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['sn'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['fname']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['literacy'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['numeracy'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['sn2'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['literacy2'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['numeracy2'] . "</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
        }}
        echo "</table>";
    }
    else{echo "not found";}

    } else {
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
    }
   mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```